# Relation emp-super

Tags: self, self-join

creat table supervisors
(
person char(20) not null,
supervisor char(20) not null,
constraint supervisor-pk primary kye(supervisor),
);
instr into supervisors
value('Bob','Alice');

instr into supervisors
value('Mary','Susan');

instr into supervisors
value('Alice','David');

instr into supervisors
value('David','Mary');

Comment: There is no question here. PS Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish. PS [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

creat table supervisors
(
person char(20) not null,
supervisor char(20) not null,
constraint supervisor-pk primary kye(supervisor),
);
instr into supervisors
value('Bob','Alice');

instr into supervisors
value('Mary','Susan');

instr into supervisors
value('Alice','David');

instr into supervisors
value('David','Mary');

select * from supervisor

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Was this trying to be an edit to the question? If so, it still doesn't ask a question & this post should be deleted because it is an answer post & you should edit your question. If not, what question is it answering & why does it answer it?? [answer]